# ¿Cómo transformar un caracter a un espacio simple en blanco?

Tags: c++, string

Pues se escucha fácil, pero como soy nuevo aún no sé mucho. Mi problema es que quiero insertar espacios en una cadena string, y sé que no se puede, pero pensé en igualar un _ a un " " como se ve en el código, tal vez sea tonto, y lo es, pero prefiero aprender que morir ignorante. :P

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string titulos[10];
    string autores[10];
    cout << "Por favor ingrese la siguiente información de los Libros: \n";

    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        string _;
        cout << "\n******* Libro " << i + 1 <<"********:\n";
        cout << "Titulo: ";
        cin >> titulos[i];
    _=" ";
        cout << "Autor: ";
        cin >> autores[i];
        cout<<"El titulo es: "<<titulos[i]<<endl;
        cout<<"El autor es: "<<autores[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Mi problema es que quiero insertar espacios en una cadena string, y sé que no se puede

Esta afirmación es rotundamente falsa. En una cadena de caracteres puedes añadir cualquier tipo de caracter. El único conflictivo es el caracter nulo `'\0'`, ya que el mismo se usa para determinar dónde finaliza la cadena de caracteres y, de usarlo en mitad de la cadena, algunas funciones relacionadas con la gestión de cadenas de texto pueden dar resultados inesperados.

Lo que sucede es que el operador de extracción de `cin` deja de leer una cadena de caracteres cuando se encuentra con un caracter separador.

Este hecho es facil de demostrar. Basta con modificar la tabla que tiene por defecto `cin` para modificar su comportamiento.

El siguiente ejemplo admitirá como separadores el símbolo del dolar y el salto de línea. Verás que a partir de ese momento `cin` leerá los espacios sin problemas:

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>

static std::ctype<char>::mask const* mis_separadores()
{
    static std::ctype<char>::mask rc[std::ctype<char>::table_size];
    rc['$'] = std::ctype_base::space;
    rc['\n'] = std::ctype_base::space;
    return rc;
}

int main()
{
 std::cin.imbue(std::locale(std::cin.getloc(), new std::ctype<char>(mis_separadores())));

  std::string word;
  while(std::cin >> word) {
    std::cout << word << "\n";
  }
}
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando [aqui](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vRfv966BWA7o6Fxr).

El problema de hacer esto es que podemos empezar a obtener comportamientos no deseados en otras funciones relacionadas con la entrada/salida, así que salvo para situaciones muy puntuales, lo mejor es no tocar esa tabla.

Además, tenemos otro motivo adicional y es que ya disponemos de una función que permite leer espacios... se trata de la función [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).

Solo hay que tener un detalle en cuenta al usar esta función, y es no se lleva demasiado bien con los usos previos de `cin`. Resulta que `cin` no elimina el último salto de línea que se encuentra. Esa responsabilidad se la deja a la siguiente llamada a `cin`. Esto hace que `getline` lea el salto de línea e interprete que ya debe dejar de leer... el efecto es que parece que `getline` no funciona... basta con usar `cin.ignore` para solucionar el problema:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  int var;
  std::cin >> var;

  std::cin.ignore(); // Descartamos el separador (normalmente un espacio o salto de línea)

  std::string cadena1;
  std::getline(std::cin, cadena1); // Leemos una línea completa

  std::string cadena2;
  std::getline(std::cin, cadena2); // llamadas consecutivas a getline no requieren llamar a ignore

  std::cout << var << '#'
            << cadena1 << '#'
            << cadena2 << '#';
}
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando [aqui](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6CJsmNZYeYvI0oTQ)

Answer (score 0):

si quieres agregar espacios a un string es muy facil, mira el siguiente ejemplo:

```
string cadena;
cadena="esto";
cadena +=" ";
cadena +="es"
cadena +=" ";
cout << cadena;
cadena +="una"
cadena +=" ";
cadena +="concatenacion"
```

Si hace lo anterior se mostrara en pantalla la siguiente oración :"esto es una concatenacion".En base a lo anterior si quieres agregar espacios a un string solamente los tienes que concatenar.Regresando a tu codigo solo aplica estoy sera mas limpio tu codigo.Y tambien un observacion , la variable _ a la que se le asigno un espacio , jamas la usaste , solo la declaraste y le asignaste un valor.

Saludos